# How much had really been ordered?

Tags: mathematics

The clerk misunderstood the order for rope. He reversed feet and inches, and the customer got only 30% of what he ordered.

How much rope had really been ordered?

Comment: This would never happen in a metric rope shop!

Answer (score 20):

> Assume the order was for $x$ feet and $y$ inches, a total of $12x+y$ inches, and the customer got $y$ feet and $x$ inches, a total of $12y+x$ inches. We know that $12x+y=\frac{10}{3}(12y+x)$, so that $36x+3y=120y+10x$, or $26x=117y$. As $\gcd(26,117)=13$, we have $2x=9y$. So for any positive integer $k$, there is a solution $x=9k,y=2k$. As @Jaap points out, $x,y\lt12$ can be assumed, therefore $k=1$, and so $x=9, y=2$.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume x<12 and y<12, because any more than 11 inches would be converted to feet. So there really is only one solution, with k=1.

Comment: Proof is more useful than brute force answers! +1

Comment: @JaapScherphuis; good point - a semi-stupid tailor!

Comment: Why x ( measurement of feet) should be less than 12?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Because then the clerk would have to have heard a very unusual way to express a measurement of feet and inches. For example, the clerk would have understood the order as "2 feet 14 inches" which would be a most unusual way of expressing the equivalent measurement of "3 feet 2 inches".

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay; because when he accidentally reversed the measurements, he would have said, say, 2feet 14inches, which would have, I suppose, rang some alarm bells in his head.

Comment: @maxathousand - this  explanation is based on 'hearing' rather than understanding by clerk.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - yes, some element of assumption is involved - rather entirely by reasoning.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay I’m not sure what you mean. Are you saying this is not a reasonable explanation of the x,<12 requirement?

Comment: It's pretty obvious what it is from the working out, but should the answer include the actual answer?

Answer (score 10):

With some trial and error:

Seems he ordered:

> 9 feet and 2 inches and received only 2 feet and 9 inches

Comment: You should have listed out the trial and error process.

Answer (score 7):

> First, we know that a foot is 12 inches.
> Let the length of the rope be $x$ feet and $y$ inches.
> In other words, the rope is $12x+y$ inches long.
> Since the clerk misunderstood, the rope he got was $y$ feet and $x$ inches long, which can also be expressed as $12y+x$ inches.
> With some trial and error, it is not hard to find that he ordered 9 feet and 2 inches of rope at first but received 2 feet and 9 inches of rope.

Answer (score 2):

> $0.3 \times (12x + y)$ is what he received, with the ordered length being $x\text{'}y\text{"}$, $12y + x$ is what the clerk understood. $0 \leq x < 12$ and $0 \leq y < 12$
>
>  $0.3 \times (12x + y) = 12y + x \Rightarrow 3.6x + 0.3y = 12y + x \Rightarrow 2.6x = 11.7y$
>  $y$ can further be limited because $\frac{11.7}{2.6}y = 4.5y < 12$, leaving us with $0 \leq y < 3$. $0$ and $1$ clearly don't work, which leaves us with $2$.
>  Set $y = 2 \Rightarrow 2.6x = 23.4 \Rightarrow x = 9$
>
>  $0.3 \times (9\text{'}2\text{"}) = 33\text{"} = 2\text{'}9\text{"}$

Answer (score 1):

If you do not place a restriction on inches, there are an infinite number of answers.  If you place the restriction that it must be less than 12, but can be any real number > 0, I believe there are still an infinite number of solutions.  If it must be an integer, then I would think there is only a finite number of solution in this case.

Either way, below outlines my process for deriving this solution:

> `12i+f = 0.3(12f+i) -> Left side is swapped inches and feet, right side is 30% of expected amount of rope`
>
>  `12i+f = 0.3i+3.6f -> Reduction`
>
>  `11.7i = 2.6f -> Reduction`
>
>  `f=4.5i => i =  2/9f -> This is a relationship between the value for inches and feet that will satisfy the requirements of this problem.`
>
>  `Arbitrarily pick a value for f => 27`
>
>  `i = 2/9*27 = 6`
>
>  `Verify solution: 12*6+27 = 0.3(12*27+6) -> True`
>
>  This will be valid for any pick for f or i.

Comment: I don't think 27 feet and 6 inches can be confused with 6 feet and 27 inches. Nobody would use 6 feet and 27 inches.
Same with 3 feet and 0.66 inches: Nobody would use 0.66 feet and 3 inches.

Comment: @Timbo 0.66 feet + 3 inches isn't that strange. Suppose you know that you have a fixed length of 0.66 feet, and for this particular project, you need to go 3 inches farther.

Comment: @blakeoft wouldn't you just specify 11" in that case?

Comment: @Baldrickk You certainly could, and most probably would. Still, they are two perfectly fine ways to represent the same measurement. Although, I'd almost definitely say 11 inches if I were asking someone to make a cut for me rather than doing it myself.

Comment: @Timbo, sure, but the question did not place such a restriction.

Comment: @BrandonDixon The question says "The clerk misunderstood the order for rope." So the question has the restriction that somebody can misunderstand it.

Comment: @Timbo you are correct if and only if the clerk has 'common sense' for lack of a better term.  I did address that point, albeit in different terms, in the beginning of my answer.